# How Do I Put A Binary File on The First Sector Of A USB Without Overwriting Important File System Data

Tags: assembly, binary, operating-system, usb, bootloader

I would like to copy a .bin bootloader to A 4gb USB drive, but when i do that, the USB disappears from devices and drives and i need to reformat it for the USB drive to come back. I copy the files using rufus (Yes, it can burn .bin files to USB drives too), but inspecting the reformatted drive with HxD, I can see that there is a lot of random stuff (probably FS data) on the first sector. Also I can see in the "Decoded Text" section of the hex editor I use that it says something about MS-DOS 5.0 and "Disk read error, press any key to restart" Or something like that.

OS Code: https://github.com/Nutty000/PlanetOS

Thanks!

Comment: Why is every word of your question capitalised?

Comment: whell... i like the looks of it... thats all.

Comment: Makes it pretty slow to read or skim, actually.  Just looks like a wall of title-case text.  Skimmability is terrible because it's hard to see sentence starts.

Comment: Ok... Now as for your question: yes, if you put your own boot loader on a disk that'll kill the FAT12 data structures and make the disk unreadable.  You can make it work by putting your boot code into the parts not used by FAT12 and filling the rest with standard FAT12 meta data (i.e. a BPB).

Comment: by saying "filling the rest" do you mean "filling the boot sector"? if so, then wouldn't overwriting the Fat32 (Btw i use Fat32 not Fat12) with a BPB still kill the usb?

Comment: @fuz also i dont think you can place a boot sector anywhere else on the drive other than the boot sector

Comment: i just realised i said "boot sector" instead of "boot loader" :) i cant edit the comment so i uploaded a new one.

Comment: If the disk is larger, it is likely that there is a partition table in the MBR (boot sector).  Your boot code again needs to make sure to preserve the partition table.  Surprisingly little space remains for your own code like this!

Comment: @fuz i still dont understand this... disk related stuff is very hard and confusing for me... do you know any webpage or somewhere where i can get more information on this

Comment: @Nutty The osdev wiki should have details.

Comment: @fuz i might have figured out what youre saying... I think. So youre saying that i should add the BPB in my boot loader and then i should be free to overwrite stuff. Did i get it right?

Comment: @Nutty If your boot loader is for a floppy-disk type medium with no partition table, you need a BPB.  If it is for a medium with a partition table, you need to preserve the partition table.  It seems more likely that the latter is the case.

Comment: @fuz its for a 4gb usb drive that is FAT32 Formatted so its for a medium with a partition table... Does this have anything to do with GPT? Because it says something about partition table

Comment: @Nutty A medium with a GPT also has a classic MBR-based partition table in front (called the protective MBR).  So yes, even then you will need to preserve the partition table.

Comment: @fuz Ok so i dont need a BPB then. But how can i put my os on the drive without breaking the FAT

Comment: @Nutty The normal approach is to first read the existing MBR, then copy the partition table on it into your MBR and then write your MBR with the partition table patched in back to the disk.

Comment: @fuz But what if i dont want to have a partition table and i just want to have a big chunk of space that is the size of the drive. I want to make it as simple as possibile because, as i said, disk related stuff is as confusing as alien language

Comment: Also by MBR you mean the first sector?

Comment: @Nutty You can just put what ever you want into the first sector, but obviously without a partition table Windows is not going to see any partitions (which is what you observed, too).  Yes, MBR is the first sector.

Comment: @fuz Ok... A truck full of questions incoming:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238513/discussion-between-nutty-and-fuz).